# Remove box shadow on right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The forms in bootstrap have a box shadow that leaves a very light shadow on the right side of the form. I need to remove that shadow on the right only so that the icon looks apart of the form.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/O35BdZv.png]

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6296/

Here's the CSS:

```
textarea,
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="month"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="week"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="color"],
.uneditable-input {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
     -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
       -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
      transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="input-append">
    <input class="span4" id="appendedInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..." style="border-right:0;">
    <span class="add-on" style="background:white;border-left:0;"><i class="icon-search" style="color:#a3a3a3"></i></span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Please help!

Comment: Came across a similar issue too; I fixed it by adding an absolutely positioned element that was a few pixels wide and that overlapped the shadow when the user interacted with the functionality. I used jQuery to trigger the positioning.

Comment: There has to be a better way than that...

Comment: The problem I had was that sometimes I needed the patch and sometimes not (similar to your situation based on input focus). So when I triggered the event that required the patch, I also showed the HTML patch and then hid it when the trigger fired again. Not hard actually.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6305/

CSS:

```
.input-append {
  position: relative;
}

.input-append .add-on {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: white;
  border-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: -32px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can relatively position `.add-on` and give it a positive `z-index` value so that it appears over the right-edge of the `<input>` - it's not 100% seamless but with some minor changes you can probably make it work for you.

```
.input-append .add-on:last-child {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6302/

Comment: I did this, but differently: [http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6305/](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6305/)

Answer (score 1):

Assign a spread-radius value of `-1px` to the box shadow and add an extra pixel to the y-offset.

> **`<spread-radius>`**
>
> This is a fourth `<length>` value. Positive values will
>   cause the shadow to expand and grow bigger, negative values will cause
>   the shadow to shrink. If not specified, it will be 0 (the shadow will
>   be the same size as the element).

[MDN: box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#Syntax) (source)

---

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6307/

#### CSS

```
input[type="text"] {
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `border-left:0px;` becouse now yu dont have a px in element style

Comment: I tried that (I think you meant border-right) and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using box-shadow for "DIV.input-append" and make transparent background to input[type=text], example of using:

**CSS:**

```
.input-append{
    position: relative;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
       -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
         -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
            transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;

}

.input-append:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/11_Search-16.png') no-repeat;
}

.input-append input[type=text]{
    background: none;
    border:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="input-append">
    <input class="span4" id="appendedInput" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EDLs7/